# Не работают относительные ссылки в CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Не получается импортировать картинку на страницу, есть вот такой каталог. Надо чтобы фоном элемента **Custom_Section** была картинка, путь прописал правильно, уже проверял. К слову, если тот же путь прописать в **HTML** в блоке **style** то всё работает хорошо.[image: Вот эта картинка, как бы фоном должна быть]

- site (папка)

  - css (папка)

    - main.css
  - img (папка)

    - clip.jpg
  - index.html

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#mean {
    height: 713px;
    background: #9A9A9A;
}

#Header {
    position: relative;
    background: #000000;
    height: 72px;
}

#Brand {
    height: 105px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#Features {
    height: 1715px;
}

#Feature_1 {
    height: 595px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
}

#Feature_2 {
    height: 596px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#Feature_3 {
    height: 524px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
}

#Our_Process {
    height: 592px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#Pricing {
    height: 883px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
}

#Testimonials {
    height: 591px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#Custom_Section {
    height: 320px;
    background: url(img/clip.jpg);
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="Header">

        </div>
        <div id="mean">
            
        </div>
        <div id="Brand">
        
        </div>
        <div id="Features">
            <div id="Feature_1">
                
            </div>
            <div id="Feature_2">
                
            </div>
            <div id="Feature_3">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Our_Process">
            
        </div>
        <div id="Pricing">
            
        </div>
        <div id="Testimonials">
            
        </div>
        <div id="Custom_Section">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если ссылки относительные, значит нужно выйти из папки css на один уровень выше `url(../img`

Comment: Б*я, ну вот что за чёрная магия ААА, я пробовал такой вариант, и он не работал, стоило только сделать тоже самое после ответа на stackoverflow, как все сразу заработало, спасибо